# Jquery Datatables delete row is not working with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I am using: jquery.dataTables.js from: https://datatables.net

my delete button  it is not working, I would like know what I am doing wrong.

If I remove the drag and drop functionality the button works fine.

someone knows what I am doing wrong?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7debwj2/24/

```
 rowReorder: {
      dataSrc: 'order',
      selector: 'tr',
    },
```

if I remove  `selector: 'tr'`,works fine, but i Can't because the whole row need be draggable

html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>order</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>country</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').dataTable();
  dt.fnDestroy();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bQzyuEGndu?indent=2';
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: url,
    rowReorder: {
      dataSrc: 'order',
      selector: 'tr',
    },
    columns: [{
      data: 'order'
    }, {
      data: 'place'
    }, {
      data: 'name'
    }, {
      data: 'delete'
    }],
    "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
      $("i.fa.fa-minus-square").click(function(event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a very small modification of the rowReorder.js I managed to make it work, hopefully it won't have any other fallback.

I changed the rowReorder.js file in line 182 from:
`return false;` to `return;`

Why?
Because Jquery has the following code:

```
ret = ( ( jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {} ).handle ||
                        handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );

                    if ( ret !== undefined ) {
                        if ( ( event.result = ret ) === false ) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    }
```

When `return false;` the `ret` value is `false` and the code:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

is being executes. [event.stopPropogation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) stops from the event to bubble and that causes your "**mousedown**" event not to work.

When we use only `return;` the condition isn't true and there is no stoppropagation of the event and it works as you can see in this Demo:
**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0HMWQQnevG4rTqtcudyp?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like rowReorder plugin covers the "mousedown" event which is before the "click" event and prevent any other handlers on it.
from https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.js:

```
$(dt.table().container()).on( 'mousedown.rowReorder touchstart.rowReorder', this.c.selector, function (e) {
            if ( ! that.c.enabled ) {
                return;
            }

            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

            // Double check that it is a DataTable row
            if ( dt.row( tr ).any() ) {
                that._mouseDown( e, tr );
                return false;
            }
        } );

        dt.on( 'destroy.rowReorder', function () {
            $(dt.table().container()).off( '.rowReorder' );
            dt.off( '.rowReorder' );
        } );
```

Comment: thank you, can you provide a jsfiddle for this? thank you so much

Comment: @Raduken in my other answer.